# Downloading BCM4321

Tags: wireless, broadcom, b43

I cannot figure out how to download this driver so that I can connect to my wireless internet:  It is the "BCM4321 80211 Linux STA driver.  I sure could use some help.

Thank you very much!

Wayne

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! IMO your question doesn't have requisite information for us to answer. Please give us more info about your Ubuntu version and why you are trying to install the driver. Many features are OOTB in Ubuntu and so you need not install drivers. Did you have any issues trying to connect to the wireless network and so are trying to install the driver? If yes, then what issues did you have?

Answer (score 0):

@user292421 - in the same directory as the download for the driver, there is a [README.txt](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php) file, which has the following quote.  You may be making a bot more work for yourself than you need to.

### > PRECOMPILED DRIVER

Some distros (Ubuntu and Fedora at the least) already have a version of
this driver in their repositories precompiled, tested and ready to go.
You just use the package manager to install the proper package.  If
its available for your distro, this is usually an easier solution. See
the end of this document for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Synaptic Package Manager installed on your Ubuntu system, start it up and type 'bcm4321' into the search bar. It lists all the packages you need and it will download and install them for you.

If you don't have Synaptic installed, I recommend you get it: you can download and install it from the Ubuntu Software Center.